# Can I make this assumption?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, solution-verification

I am solving this question:

Let $ABC$ be an acute angled triangle and $CD$ be the altitude through $C$. If $AB=8$ and $CD=6$, find the distance between the midpoints of BC and AD.

So I observed that there are an infinite number of such triangles which satisfy $AB=8$ and $CD=6$ with $CD \perp AB$. So I can move $B$ closer to $D$ and $A$ away from $D$ to keep $AB$ constant. So what I did is I coincided $B$ and $D$ so the problem became much easier to solve. And I got the correct answer of $5$.

But if I coincide $B$ and $D$ then $\triangle ABC$ is no longer acute angled but rather right angled. So how can I use this approach of solving the problem in a subjective test without breaking the assumption that $ABC$ is acute angled?

Comment: You can't use this approach. If this weren't a designed question, there is no guarantee that the distance would remain constant by changing the angle

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan I beg to differ. The OP is not asking about applying this approach in a bunch of geometry problems, but rather this specific question. Since the distance you have to compute does not depend on the inner angles of the triangle, it still would work if one of the angles were $90-\epsilon$, so, by continuity, it would also be the same for a right triangle.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan No the length does remain constant because there are too few conditions to construct a triangle, but of course there is only one solution to the problem. That's how I concluded that the distance must remain the same even if I move  A and B as long as AB=8.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan What Bcpicao said is right, I only want to use the approach for this one problem.

Comment: I didn't understand the question, is it how to use this approach and turn it into a subjective answer, or is it to solve the question in a way suitable for a subjective exam?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan I am asking how to use this approach and turn it into a subjective answer.

Comment: I edited my comment with a concise explanation.

Comment: An embedded assumption in your approach is that the measure is constant - I think that part of the challenge is to prove that the required distance is constant and than the measure. You are lucky that this turns true! Prove it.

Comment: You could consider the special case $AC=BC$, where it is evident that the distance from the midpoint of $AD$ to the projection on $AB$ of the midpoint of $BC$ is $4$. But a little thought suggests this to be always the case.

Comment: You can not make the assumption - you need to compute this specific case and show that it is invariant under the different structures!

Comment: @Moti That is my question. How can I prove it?

Comment: Will you accept the answer - as appreciation for the effort?

Comment: @Moti, sorry that doesn't answer my question. You just gave a solution. I wanted a subjective answer which would make use of the coinciding points with proper proof because the triangle becomes right-angled if I coincide the points and it is no longer acute.

Comment: I want proof of two things:  

1) The length of EF will remain the same even if I move A and B.

2) The length of EF will remain the same even if the triangle is right-angled, i.e, if I coincide B and D.

Comment: I think that you do not understand the answer! The two questions you raised are answered by this solution - you can move A and B (Or just slide C) and it also meets the distance invariant if B coincide with D (or C is slide over B). Try with GeoGebra to see this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is quite clear:

[image]